# Prove that the following set is a subvector space of $\mathbb{R}[X]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that the following set is a subvector space of $\mathbb{R}[X]$

$M := \{{f \in R[X] : f(X-1) = f(X)]}\}$

I am not sure how an element of this set could look like. I constructed the following example

$f_1 \in M := \{k_0\} $ Since $f_1(X-1)= f_1(X) = k_0 $

However I find it hard to find other examples since it seems it all depends on the coefficients.

Since I can not imagine how the elements look like in general I can not check if for example (o,o,o,o,o…...o) is also in this set. Could someone explain to me how the elements of such a set look like? thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help. Clearly, the constant functuons are contained in this set. If $f$ is not constant, then $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = f(k)$ for all integers $k$. Then you need to show that any such polynomial is acrually constant, so this set is just the constant funcrions which is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have the following sofar. Assumption only constant functions are included.
Proof. Let $g \in M$ such that $g$ is not a constant. then follows for $g$
$k_0 + k_1.(x-1)^1 + k_2 . (x-1)^2 +...…. = k_0 + k_1 . x + k_2 . x^2 + ……….$ 
for $x=0: k_0 - k_1 + k_2+...….. = k_0 $ thus $-k_1 +k_2 - k_3 +k_4...... = 0$ and its constant. 
Same follows for 1,2,3...…..k etc?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f ∈ ℝ[X]$. If $f(X - 1) = f(X)$, then evaluating $f$ is constant on $ℤ$ by induction. Hence …?